# RabbitMQ - Message published, but not routed

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, message-queue, rabbitmq-exchange

We have a 5 pods 3.8.5 rabbitmq deployment on k8s using the bitnami helm chart, sometimes after a pod restart it seems that lots (but not all) routing keys on multiple exchanges stopped working with "Message published, but not routed." error. after rebinding the routing key it seems OK.

We've seen articles about this issue but with no answer on how to resolve it, for example:

1. https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/149/718757594
2. https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/X4QllrunYGY

does anyone knows the answer to this issue?

Comment: You have to add a policy to direct messages to an alternate queue as described here: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/l0-h048ztw8/m/LXUy088WEQAJ
by Michał Kuratczyk from the RabbitMQ team.  This worked for me.